# Sending ApplicationInfo from one activity to another

Tags: android

This is how I send it

```
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Permissions.class);
        i.putExtra("AppSelected",installedApps.get((int) id));
        startActivity(i);
```

THis is how I retrieve it:

```
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        ApplicationInfo a = extras.get[What do I put here?]("AppSelected");
```

I cannot seem to figure out get this to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: ApplicationInfo is `Parcelable`  ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: Actually, it is -- I needed to look that up myself.

Comment: I cannot seem to get any of these to works. 

To put my issue more simply I want to take an instance of ApplicationInfo and use its Fields in another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `getParcelable()` on the `Bundle` to retrieve your `ApplicationInfo` (which implements the `Parcelable` interface). You will need to cast the result to `ApplicationInfo`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what that means. Does getParcelable() get the entire app object?

Comment: @user3293569: "Does getParcelable() get the entire app object?" -- yes, for whatever the implementation of `ApplicationInfo` considers "the entire app object" to be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `installedApps.get...` returns an integer, you should change your code

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

for

```
int appId = getIntent().getIntExtra("AppSelected", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve any extra just use the key that you use to save value plus a default in some case
    example

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     int example = extras.getIntExtra("key", int defaultValue) ;//to retrieve an Integer
     String example = extras.getStringExtra("key"); //to retrieve a String
```

.....son so forth

```
    in your case 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    ApplicationInfo a = extras.getIntExtra("AppSelected", 0);
```